# Passing a list to a function python

Tags: python, list, function

```
def parsePlayer(self,item,response):    #this one works like it should

    item['playerurl'] = re.findall(r'"[^"]*"',"".join(item['playerurl'])) 
    print(item['playerurl'])


def parsePlayer(self,item,response):    #this one does not work like it should

    item['playerurl'] = self.playerurls(item['playerurl'])
    print(item['playerurl'])


def playerurls(*exlist):
    listed = []
    sampString = "".join(exlist)
    listed = re.findall(r'"[^"]*"',sampString)
    return listed
```

I'm attempting to create a function that will do what the first parsePlayer function does. I'm hoping the playerurls function can take a list and then do a regex function to extract all parts of the string which are in quotations, this is not where I'm having trouble.

I am having trouble in writing the playerurls function. I keep getting this: "exceptions.TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, NbastatsSpider found" @

```
sampString = "".join(exlist)
```

NbastatsSpider is the name of the spider that fills the 'playerurl' field of the item I created. I don't get why I'm getting this error because I'm passing in a list, turning it into a string, doing the regex function to the string and finally returning a list. There must be an error in passing the list (item['playerurl']) to the function. Either that or I'm confusing myself with using the 'self.' parameter.

Comment: Don't put `*` before `exlist`. That's used when the list is spread into multiple arguments, not passed as a single list.

Comment: exceptions.TypeError: playerurls() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

I tried that before and got this error...

Comment: Are these functions being defined within a `class` declaration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
def playerurls(self, exlist):
```

You need a `self` argument because you're calling it as `self.playerurls`. You don't need `*` before the `exlist` argument: that's used when the elements of the list are passed as separate arguments.

I'm not sure why you're using `self` in the first place. None of these functions refer to any instance variables of `self`.

Comment: Missing colon in the snippet there.  Also, based on the OP's comments, I think the function in question is actually a method of some class, possible `NbastatsSpider`.

Comment: It may be, but it doesn't seem to need to be, since it doesn't do anything to the class. But maybe he's simplified it.

Comment: @augurar is correct, it is a method of that class but I defined it in the class. Barmar thanks, it worked - I thought I needed the * but I will keep your previous comment in mind for the future

Comment: @Barmar I am confused as to why you said that I should not use self. I attempted to search why this is the case and I still think I should use it. The reason being, playerurls is defined previously in my class, it is a property of a data type that I created. Would this not qualify as an instance variable because I created it in the class? If this is not the case, do you know any tutorials, or articles that can better explain the topic to me? Thanks. 

Also I claim to be a self taught programmer, so I'm attempting to follow patterns in the tutorials that I'm using to learn.

Comment: `playerurls` doesn't make use of any class properties. It doesn't do anything specific to your class, it just performs general-purpose list and string processing.